# Is there a standard command-line tool to do a hostname lookup?

Tags: linux, shell

I am in the shell and I want to know the corresponding IP address(es) for a hostname.

I know I could get it through Perl, PHP, Python or a number of other scripting languages (probably even awk!), and this will be my workaround, but I am surprised that there seems to be no command-line tool to do this, no simple wrapper around `getaddrinfo()`.

Am I wrong? Is there one? `host`, `dig` and `getent` do not count, I want something that uses the libc and acts according to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and something that is probably installed on any (linux) system by default.

Moved here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211326/is-there-a-standard-command-line-tool-to-do-a-hostname-lookup

Answer: I was wrong, `getent` does not exclusively look in `/etc/hosts`, it actually does a proper lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the traditional tool for doing host name lookups is nslookup from bind, but it is being replaced with dig. both tools are dns speciffic and don't use nsswitch. getent hosts uses nsswitch, but much less used.

Comment: `getent` does not use nsswitch, it exclusively looks in the `hosts` file, `host` and `dig` ignore the `hosts` file.

Comment: from the man page "getent - get entries from Name Service Switch libraries" and "
hosts     When  no  key  is provided, use sethostent(3), gethostent(3), and endhostent(3) to enumerate the hosts database.  When one or more key arguments are provided, pass each key to gethostbyaddr(3) or gethostby‐name2(3), depending on whether a call to inet_pton(3) indicates that the key is an IPv6 or IPv4 address or not, and display the result." so if it locks the hosts files, that is how your nsswitch.conf is setup. If you remove files it won't.

Comment: Btw, where is that man page from? My man page in Ubuntu is not that clear, it simply says `gathers entries from the specified administrative database using the specified search keys. Where database is one of passwd, group, hosts, services, protocols, or networks.` (Ubuntu 12.04, manpage inherited from Debian Lenny)

Comment: And RHEL has no manpage at all. Found yours at http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent , but I wonder what their source is.

Comment: I run debian stable and that man page is from version 3.44-1 of the manpages package.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html "This page is part of release 3.54 of the Linux man-pages project.  A
       description of the project, and information about reporting bugs, can
       be found at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/.
" ooooh.

Comment: Seems they added it in `wheezy` then, and Ubuntu has or will inherit it in later versions than my `precise`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install manpages/saucy` `man getent` Yay! I feel better now. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @clacke remember that the new man pages might not match your tools.

Comment: You are of course right. But for the most part, the tools covered by these manpages are stable since last millennium. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`getent` is certainly the right tool for the job but it is unfortunately not available everywhere, one of the reason being it is not mandatory being undefined by POSIX.

On the other hand, while it isn't either specified by the standard, `arp` is very unlikely not to be available on any server that does name resolution. As `arp` follows `nsswitch.conf` settings, only uses `libc`, is available on any Linux/Unix system, and provides an output that seems to be consistent between implementations, parsing its output would do the job:

```
$ arp stackoverflow.com | sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/).*$//'
198.252.206.16
```

Here is a shell function that uses that method, avoiding an issue with Linux arp which switch to a different output format in some corner cases:

```
resolve()
{
  : ${1:?Usage: resolve name}
  (
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
    ao=$(arp $1)
    [ "$(echo "$ao"|grep HWaddress)" ] && ao=$(arp -a $1)
    echo "$ao" | sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/).*$//'
  )
}
```

Comment: I have yet to see a glibc-based distribution that does not come with the glibc command-line tools installed. Such a distribution may exist, but `getent` definitely fits my requirements.

Comment: Your question ruled out `getent` and I assumed that was because of its unavailability on some Linux platform you were working on. `getent` seems to be mainstream with current Linux distributions but that wasn't the case many years ago. It first appeared on Solaris and I believe many Unix outside those Solaris & Linux based are still missing `getent` for the reasons I posted.